# threads of one process can run on more than one physical CPUs?

Tags: linux, multithreading, smp

on Linux, we have two physical CPUs (not multi-cores), one process named X has many threads.

Question is if it is possible:  some threads of X running on one CPU, while some other threads of X running on the other CPU at the same time??

Answer (score 1):

I searched, and have some OS knowledge:  the history and mode of thread impl.

there is: M:N, N:1, 1:1.

while on linux, NPTL is 1:1 model, 1 thread corresponding to 1 kernel thread.  => yes, threads of one process on linux can run on different CPUs.